# How to append dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

Basically i have a REST api which return a JSON . In this JSON , it return the last viewed topic. For example

```
{ lastview : ABC }
```

So i want to insert this to my page

```
<div class = 'lastview'>Last viewed topic: </div>

$.getJSON("json link", function(data){
 $('<a/>',{
 text: data.lastview
 }).appendTo('.lastview');
```

But since this data may change after another topic is viewed. What i mean is if user go to another topic name XYZ , the JSON change lastview from ABC to XYZ but the one in web will not ( still ABC ) because it only execute the function one time when the page loads.

So is there anyway to dynamically check the JSON and return correctly when the content changes ( What i mean is when the lastview topic change to XYZ , the one in div will automatically change to XYZ too)

Thanks

Comment: One way is to keep polling for data (Let say, `setTimeout` every 500ms)

Comment: You mean call the function to execute every 500ms ? I feel this method will make the page become lagging

Comment: There is no way to know if there is an update unless using other API like WebSocket / Web Push notification, this will required changing both frontend and backend, REST can only Pull but not Push

Answer (score 0):

The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

1000 ms = 1 second.

The function is only executed once. If you need to repeat execution, use the setInterval() method.

```
setInterval({

$.getJSON("json link", function(data){

$('<a/>',
       {

         text: data.lastview

       }).appendTo('.lastview');


 }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of keep requesting and update every 500ms

```js
setInterval(function() {
    // Fake ajax
    data = { lastview: "Page " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) };
    // Just for demo
    
    $("#lastview").empty();
    $("#lastview").append(
        $("<a></a>").text(data.lastview)
    );
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Last viewed topic: <span id="lastview"></span></div>
```